# What is the VC dimension of a d-dimensional quadratic function?

Tags: machine-learning

I have an indicator function $I(M, x, y) = sign[(M(x - u))^{T} (M(x - u)) - y]$.

$M$ is an invertible matrix of size $d \times d$.

$x, u$ are vectors of size $d$. $u$ is a parameter for the indicator function. $y \in \mathcal{R}$.

What is the VC dimension for such a function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful start. Notice that
\begin{align}
(M(x-u))^T M(y-u) 
&= (x-u)^T M^T M(y-u). 
\end{align}

Let

- $a = (x-u).$ So $a \in \mathbf{R}^d$.
- $b= (y-u).$ So $b \in \mathbf{R}^d$.
- $W = M^T M.$ So $W \in \mathbf{R}^{d\times d}$.
- $X = ab^T.$ So $X \in \mathbf{R}^{d\times d}$.

Then
\begin{align}
(x-u)^T M^T M(y-u)
&= a^T W b \\
&= \sum_{i,j} W_{ij} \, a_i \, b_j \\
&= \sum_{i,j} W_{ij} (a b^T)_{ij} \\
&= \sum_{i,j} W_{ij} \, X_{ij} \\
&= \langle W, X \rangle_{\text{matrix}}
\end{align}
where $\langle \cdot\,, \cdot \rangle_{\text{matrix}}$ is an inner product on $d\times d$ matrices, which here can be thought of as vectors with  $d^2$ entries. (See the wikipedia entry on the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product).)

In other words, your original function $I(M,x,y) = \text{sign}[(M(x-u))^T M(y-u)]$ looks just like a perceptron, $f(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{w}) = \text{sign}(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x})$ but where the input vectors $X$ have dimension $d^2$ rather than $d$.

One thing that's unclear in your question is whether "$u$" and "$M$" are part of the inputs to shatter, or whether they are the model parameters.

Assuming they are the model parameters, then the VC-dimension of the function "$I$" is going to be related to the VC-dimension of the perceptron on $d^2$-dimensional inputs. I say "related to" rather than "equal to" because the inputs $X = ab^T$ are constrained to be rank-1 matrices, and therefore not all $d^2$-input patterns are possible. And I'm not sure whether this changes the answer to the original question...

Comment: Can you help me figure out the solution to the original problem, continuing from here? The problem could be reduced to a perceptron with some constraints on its parameters, but is there a theorem that says adding constraints will reduce the VC dimension?

Comment: Well, I was assuming M and u were model parameters, not inputs, so the problem is very different. In fact, if the inputs are the tuples (x,y,M,u), then the VC dimension is 0 because we are just talking about the VC dimension of the "sign" function, which can't shatter any set of points.